# Interpret arithmetic expression C++

Tags: c++, optimization, integer-overflow, std, arithmetic-expressions

I am writing a C++ program that reads one line of input from stdin, interpret it as an arithmetic expression (addition and multiplication), evaluate it and write out the result.

It can be assumed that the integers fit in a single 32‐bit unsigned int and result also fits in a 32‐bit unsigned int and inputs do not cause integer overflow. I have been advised to not to use parse tree.

Also the program should be able to support parentheses for grouping and detect integer overflow during evaluation. I have pasted the code below.

I am looking for suggestions to improve and optimize it further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int calcSum();
int calcProd();
vector<int> num_vector;
vector<char> op_vector;
int op_count=0,num_count=0;

int main(){
    string expr,operand;
    getline(cin,expr);
    for(size_t i=0;i<expr.size();i++){
        bool insert =0;int number =0;
        if(expr[i] >= '0' && expr[i] <= '9'){
            operand += expr[i];
            if(i==expr.size()-1) insert=1;
        }
        else if(((expr[i] == '+' || expr[i] == '*' || expr[i] == ' ') && (expr[i+1] >= '0' && expr[i+1] <= '9'))){
            insert = 1;
        }
        if(expr[i] == '+' || expr[i]== '*') op_vector.push_back(expr[i]);

        if(insert){
            stringstream newop(operand);
            newop >> number;
            num_vector.push_back(number);
            operand = "";
        }   
    }
    int result = calcSum();cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}

int calcSum(){
    int val1 = calcProd();
    while(op_vector[op_count] == '+'){
        ++op_count;
        int val2 = calcProd();
        val1 = val1 + val2;
    }
    return val1;
}

int calcProd(){
    int val1 = num_vector[num_count];num_count++;
    while(op_vector[op_count] == '*'){
        ++op_count;
        int val2 = num_vector[num_count];num_count++;
        val1 = val1 * val2;
    }
    return val1;
}
```

Comment: Tip: `switch` is something you'll need to pick up on eventually, and it'd help a ton here. Another thing to note is you're going to want to write functions to split this up into separate concerns instead of jamming everything in `main()`.

Comment: Thanks @tadman for your quick reply. I am on them.
Do you have any suggestions on improving Time and Space Complexity?
Also, is it a good way to use global variables?

Comment: When it comes to global variables the easy answer is *don't use them*. Always pass through data as arguments. This helps considerably with debugging, and also if you ever thread this code you won't be in a world of hurt out of the gate. As for time and space complexity it's really hard to say since there's a lot going on here and none of it is documented. Most of the code has opaque variable names like `val1` and such, which impairs easy understanding.

Comment: Since this is C++ the solution should take the form of some kind of `class` that can be fed in *input* and produce a *result*. As in `auto calc = new Calculator()` and then `auto result = calc.compute("...")` You'll also want to pick a [unit testing framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C++) to help steer your development and ensure it behaves correctly. [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) is a great example to work from, it's just one header file.

Comment: Thanks again. I am re-writing some parts of my code now. One more thing, how do i deal with supporting parentheses for grouping and detect integer overflow during evaluation ??

Comment: One way to detect overflows is to use an integer type bigger than your final result, e.g. 64-bit int to do 32-bit calculations. If your number exceeds the bounds you can handle the error accordingly. The alternative is to examine both values prior to performing a mathematical operation to ensure they're within acceptable bounds.

Comment: You wrote _"result also fits in a 32‐bit unsigned int and inputs do not cause integer overflow"_ and _"how do i ... detect integer overflow during evaluation ??"_ Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because _"suggestions to improve and optimize"_ sounds like something more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than for Stack Overflow.